# Parsing text within a taxonomy.csv file

Tags: r, phylogenetics, taxonomy, parsing

I have the following file in tab separated values (TSV).

| ID | Taxonomy |
| --- | --- |
| 76980f6d906c6baaef3f96559fc7ba1b | d__Eukaryota; p__Cercozoa; c__Vampyrellidae; o__Vampyrellidae; f__Vampyrellidae; g__uncultured |
| 4f808d3adec894395304661391037369 | d__Eukaryota; p__Ochrophyta; c__Xanthophyceae; o__uncultured; f__uncultured; g__uncultured |
| 777584465097568f5b30bc9e2b6584c1 | d__Eukaryota; p__Labyrinthulomycetes; c__uncultured; o__uncultured; f__uncultured; g__uncultured |
| 5a99dafabe78847d8f5fed0d37f8672a | d__Eukaryota; p__Labyrinthulomycetes; c__Labyrinthulomycetes; o__Labyrinthulomycetes; f__Thraustochytriaceae; g__uncultured |

I would like to modify the "g__uncultured" with the last known rank possibly using either shell or R scripts.

The new table would then read:

| ID | Taxonomy |
| --- | --- |
| 76980f6d906c6baaef3f96559fc7ba1b | d__Eukaryota; p__Cercozoa; c__Vampyrellidae; o__Vampyrellidae; f__Vampyrellidae; g__f__Vampyrellidae |
| 4f808d3adec894395304661391037369 | d__Eukaryota; p__Ochrophyta; c__Xanthophyceae; o__uncultured; f__uncultured; g__c__Xanthophyceae |
| 777584465097568f5b30bc9e2b6584c1 | d__Eukaryota; p__Labyrinthulomycetes; c__uncultured; o__uncultured; f__uncultured; g__p__Labyrinthulomycetes |
| 5a99dafabe78847d8f5fed0d37f8672a | d__Eukaryota; p__Labyrinthulomycetes; c__Labyrinthulomycetes; o__Labyrinthulomycetes; f__Thraustochytriaceae; g__f__Thraustochytriaceae |

Comment: It would help if you could provide your attempts to solve this, it would be easier to help you fix the issue than propose an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `pandas` solution is here:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

path = '/Whatever'
infile = 'myfile.csv'
outfile = 'outfile.csv'
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)
df = pd.read_csv(Path(path,infile), sep='\t')
taxaChange = {'76980f6d906c6baaef3f96559fc7ba1b':'g__f__Vampyrellidae', '4f808d3adec894395304661391037369':'g__c__Xanthophyceae'}
df2 = df.set_index('ID')
df3 = df2
for x,y in taxaChange.items():
    df3.loc[x, 'Taxonomy'] = df2.loc[x, 'Taxonomy'].replace('g__uncultured', y)
print (df3)

df.to_csv(Path(path,outfile), sep='\t')
```

Output

```
ID                                       Taxonomy                                                                                                                                             
76980f6d906c6baaef3f96559fc7ba1b         d__Eukaryota; p__Cercozoa; c__Vampyrellidae; o__Vampyrellidae; f__Vampyrellidae; g__f__Vampyrellidae
4f808d3adec894395304661391037369         d__Eukaryota; p__Ochrophyta; c__Xanthophyceae; o__uncultured; f__uncultured; g__c__Xanthophyceae
777584465097568f5b30bc9e2b6584c1         d__Eukaryota; p__Labyrinthulomycetes; c__uncultured; o__uncultured; f__uncultured; g__uncultured
5a99dafabe78847d8f5fed0d37f8672a         d__Eukaryota; p__Labyrinthulomycetes; c__Labyrinthulomycetes; o__Labyrinthulomycetes; f__Thraustochytriaceae; g__uncultured
```

Both `g__f__Vampyrellidae` and `g__c__Xanthophyceae` are there, i.e. the code was tested and worked fine.

The point for the `pandas` approach is you've a natural table format so it makes sense to take it straight to a dataframe (table -> dataframe). regex-ing using `\t` and `\n` is of course the alternative and you need to formulate the table as a hash (Perl) or dictionary (Python).

**Notes** The `df` and `df2` can reduced a single dataframe by updating the `df` (`inplace` was omitted and will work for an index), rather than creating a new `df`. However, the `df3` is needed (need to copy the dataframe) because 'inplace' didn't work. `inplace` is a command to force the dataframe to update. The `set_option` is just so I can print the display without truncation.

*Finally*
You substitute the infile and outfile to correct path and name values, save it as a `.py` file and just `python3 myscript.py`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, my tsv file was only an example. I've a lot of g__uncultured that should be replaced. Hence, the taxaChange should be something more general, able to parse different lines.

Comment: Hi @Marco. This does answer the specific question in my view and the code was tested and worked fine. It is 70% towards a generalised solution. However, automating the code to process lots of stuff is a separate question as general principle and particularly because its not clear how you want to do that (there are no indicators except for the above comment). I suspect you've got something is specific in mind. You can use this code as the basis for that question if you wish to pursue a `pandas` solution. `pandas` is "trendy", but there are lots of ways to do this.